# To get the last working day of the previous month when we give today's date in Powershell

Tags: powershell, date, batch-file

I have a requirement to create a folder with *last working day of the previous month* in powershell code or batch script

for example - if I am running a batch today with the date 09/14/2017 then the folder should create a date with 08312017

here is my code snippet

**filename.ps1**

```
$MonthEndDate= ((get-date -day 1).adddays(-1)).ToShortDateString()
```

**Monthenddate.bat**

```
@echo on

FOR /F %%i IN ('powershell "%~dp0filename.ps1" //Nologo') do SET MYDATE=%%i
echo %MYDATE%

 MKDIR %MYDATE%

 :END
```

Can someone help on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution presented as a reusable function:

```
Function Get-LastWorkingDayPrevMonth ($Date = (Get-Date)) {
    (-1..-7 | ForEach-Object { (Get-Date $Date -day 1).AddDays($_) } | Where-Object DayOfWeek -notin 'Saturday','Sunday') | Select -First 1
}

#Uses current date by default to return the last working day of the previous month
(Get-LastWorkingDayPrevMonth).ToString('ddMMyyyy')

#Based on specific date
(Get-LastWorkingDayPrevMonth 05/2017).ToString('ddMMyyyy')
```

The function works by getting the dates of the last 7 days of any month, filtering out any that are Saturday or Sunday and then selecting the first date in that list (which will be the latest). It then uses the `ToString` method on the resultant Date object to convert it to the string format you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `do{}while()` loop to subtract one day until the `DateTime` variable is *not* on a Saturday or Sunday:

```
# Define non-workdays
$weekend = [System.DayOfWeek]::Saturday,[System.DayOfWeek]::Sunday

# Get first day of current month
$date = Get-Date -Day 1
do{
    # Subtract one day
    $date = $date.AddDays(-1)
} while($weekend -contains $date.DayOfWeek) # until a weekday is reached
```

Comment: @Mathias is there a good reason to use `[System.DayOfWeek]::Saturday,[System.DayOfWeek]::Sunday` vs just Saturday & Sunday as strings? Does the former perhaps handle language/locale variants where as the string versions do not? Or is just more explicit in general?

Comment: @MarkWragg In this particular case there's no functional difference, but I like to be explicit when posting examples, rather than making people think 'Sunday' is some magic sort of string :-) There's also the benefit that `[Enum]::ValueName -eq $something` will always work regardless of whether `$something` is the string (`'Sunday'`), value type (`0`) or enum (`[DayOfWeek]::Sunday`) representation of the left-hand side value

Comment: Ah good point, because `[System.DayOfWeek]::Saturday -eq 6` but `'Saturday' -ne 6` !

Comment: Exactly, enum literal will also work regardless of operator overload

Answer (score 0):

Since there is always another alternative in PowerShell coding :

```
$LWDPM = (Get-Date -Day 1).AddDays(-1)
While (!([int]$LWDPM.DayOfWeek % 6)){$LWDPM=$LWDPM.AddDays(-1)}
```

---

- of course LWDPM means LastWorkingDayPreviousMonth ;-)
- The formula `[int]$LWDPM.DayOfWeek % 6` returns zero for Sunday=0 and Saturday=6
- the `!` negates this, so while weekend `.AddDays(-1)`

Wrapped in a batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\14\SO_46218430.cmd
@Echo off
For /f %%A in (
  'powershell -NoP -C "$DT=(Get-Date -Day 1).AddDays(-1);While (!([int]$DT.DayOfWeek %% 6)){$DT=$DT.AddDays(-1)};$DT.ToString(\"MMddyyyy\")"'
) do Set MyDate=%%A
Echo MyDate=%MyDate%
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_46218430.cmd
MyDate=08312017
```