# Printing from an autosys calendar

Tags: autosys

I have a standard autosys calendar for last biz of the month. My requirement is that I need to pass the last biz day of the previous month to another script when executing on the last biz day of this month. I was able to export the calendar using autocal_asc command. And iam running this using powershell script. Is there a command in autosys that can give me the last biz day of the previous month from the calendar?

Thanks,
Aron

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing native to autosys that can do that.

For the powershell try this:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218430/to-get-the-last-working-day-of-the-previous-month-when-we-give-todays-date-in-p)

Dave