# .bat script to copy file with tomorrow's date

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat script to copy a file that has tomorrow's date in the name. This script works, however if the month has less than 31 days, the script does not give the current date correctly.

The file has comments in Brazilian Portuguese.

Can someone help me?

```batch-file
@echo off
chcp 850

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 

rem Obtenha a data atual em formato MM/DD/YYYY

    set "MES=%date:~0,2%"
    set "DIA=%date:~3,2%"
    set "ANO=%date:~6,4%"


rem Atualize a data para representar o dia seguinte
set /a "DIA=%DIA% + 1"

rem Verifique se o mês ultrapassa 12 (dezembro)
if %DIA% gtr 31 (
    set "DIA=1"
    set /a "MES=%MES% + 1"
    
    if %MES% gtr 12 (
        set "MES=1"
        set /a "ANO=%ANO% + 1"
    )
)

rem Formate a data para ter dois dígitos
set "DIA=0%DIA%"

rem Construa o nome do arquivo com a nova data
set "NOVA_DATA=VM_%DIA%-%MES%-%ANO%.mp3"

rem Construa os caminhos completos para os diretórios e arquivos
set "ORIGEM=C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\CLOUD BEACH\Gratuitos - Gospel\PM - Vida Melhor\%NOVA_DATA%"
set "DESTINO=C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\CLOUD BEACH\AUTODJ\AUTODJ - Gratuitos - Gospel\AutoDJ - Vida Melhor\VM.mp3"

rem Verifique a existência do arquivo com a nova data
if exist "%ORIGEM%" (
    copy /b "%ORIGEM%" "%DESTINO%"
) else (
    del /s /q "%DESTINO%"
)

rem Exiba uma mensagem na tela
echo.
echo ╔══════════════════════════════╗
echo ║  Favor não forçar o teclado    ║
echo ╚══════════════════════════════╝
echo.


echo "Data Atual: %DIA%-%MES%-%ANO%"
```

I would like the "Current Date" variable to provide the date of the next day, regardless of the number of days in the month.
The PC running this script is Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think I have seen someone handle days within months natively in batch scripts, it takes a lot (relative to what you're trying to do) of code to achieve it, while things like Powershell can natively handle it easily.

Within your code you could add the following :

`FOR /F %%i IN ('powershell.exe -command "& {(Get-Date).AddDays(1) | Get-Date -Format MMddyyyy}"') DO (set TOMORROWDATE=%%i)`

which will then result in `%tomorrowdate%` holding tomorrow's date, by calling Powershell, getting that to spit out tomorrow's date, and saving that to the variable.

Based on your code (Google translate tells me MES is short for Month), I've set it to output in MMddyyyy format currently, so today would show as 09062023, but it can be tweaked if needed, for instance `-Format MM-dd-yyyy` would change the output to be 09-06-2023 etc.

Comment: @Compo No, not until after I'd submitted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is true that Batch file facilities are less powerful than the equivalent in PowerShell, VBScript, and other scripting languages, it is also true that Batch files are powerful enough to solve simple problems, like this one. Batch's bad reputation in this regard is due to the fact that *programmers* often take a poor approach when creating a Batch file (but the same thing can happen in PowerShell or VBScript).

This *simple* Batch file solves your problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get current date (with Day+1) from WMIC command,
rem at same time, get the number of days in February
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get Day^,Month^,Year') do (
   set /A "Day=1+%%a, Month=%%b, Year=%%c, Feb=28+!(Year%%4)"  2>NUL
)

rem If Day+1 is greater than current DaysPerMonth, fix the date
for /F "tokens=%Month%" %%d in ("31 %Feb% 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31") do (
   if %Day% gtr %%d set /A "Day=1, Month+=1, NextM=!(Month-13), Month-=NextM*12, Year+=NextM"
)

rem Adjust Day and Month values for left zeros
set /A "Day+=100, Month+=100"

set "NOVA_DATA=VM_%Day:~1%-%Month:~1%-%Year%.mp3"
echo %NOVA_DATA%
```

---

You could also solve this problem in a *very different way* using my **printf.exe** version 2.11 program.

My printf.exe application is a Windows console program that is a wrapper for the well-known [printf CRT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN), thus allowing text and formatted numeric values ​​to be displayed in the cmd.exe window. In addition, my program printf.exe also allows to perform [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) arithmetic operations on 32-bit integers and 64-bit *double* floating-point numbers using the same method and functions of the stack-based [Hewlett-Packard calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_calculators#Characteristics).

The new printf.exe version 2.11 also manages character string operations and allows to write scripts (*programs*) using the simplest programming scheme. The Batch file below contains a printf.exe program that also solves this problem. Note that the printf.exe's method (clearly explained in the extensive comments) use *simpler* (lower level) instructions, but for the same reason, simpler to understand...

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get current Day, Month, Year
rem (this could also be done in the printf code)
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get Day^,Month^,Year') do (
   set /A "Day=%%a, Month=%%b, Year=%%c"  2>NUL
)

rem The printf.exe program below uses Integer storage registers R1..R12
rem to store the (corresponding) number of days per Month
rem and: R13=Day, R14=Month, R15=Year

printf ^
    "VM_%%02i-%%02i-%%4i.mp3\n"         /*  Output format */ ^
    31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31 /* Days Per Month */ ^
    12 ]I /" < /"       /* RI = Index of R12 and drop it  */ ^
    (                   /* FOR /L RI IN (12,-1,1) DO (    */ ^
       ]i               /*    Store 31,30,31...           */ ^
       /" < /"          /*    Drop it                     */ ^
       ]--I             /*    Decrement I                 */ ^
       [I ==0? ;        /*    Is zero? : QUIT             */ ^
       /" < /"          /*    Drop the RI                 */ ^
    :                   /* NEXT RI                        */ ^
    )                   /* )                              */ ^
    Year atoi ].5       /* R15 = Year                     */ ^
    ( 4 ( %%? )?        /* IF Year MOD 4 is zero ?        */ ^
        ]++2            /*     Increment Days In February */ ^
    )                   /* ENDIF                          */ ^
    Month atoi ]I ].4   /* RI = Month, R14 = Month        */ ^
    day atoi ++ ].3     /* R13 = Day+1                    */ ^
    [i                  /* Day+1  DaysPerMonth            */ ^
    ( /" <=? /"         /* IF Day+1 GTR DaysPerMonth      */ ^
        1 ].3           /*     Day = 1                    */ ^
        ]++.4           /*     Month += 1                 */ ^
        ( [.4 13 ==?    /*     IF Month EQU 13            */ ^
            1 ].4       /*         Month = 1              */ ^
            ]++.5       /*         Year += 1              */ ^
        )               /*     ENDIF                      */ ^
    )                   /* ENDIF                          */ ^
    /" <* /"            /* Clear Stack                    */ ^
    [.3 [.4 [.5 OUT     /* Show result: Day-Month-Year    */ ^
 > result.txt

set /P "NOVA_DATA=" < result.txt
echo %NOVA_DATA%
```

Although it may seem complicated, the printf.exe instructions are *very simple*. HP calculator users can start writing printf.exe programs in minutes after understanding the differences and the programming scheme. You can review another example of a printf.exe program at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026292/windows-batch-script-to-replace-some-strings-if-another-string-is-present-in-the/77030637#77030637)

You can download the printf.exe package from [this link](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7312&p=68956#p68956)